# Tortoise svnversion.exe is invalid error in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svn, tortoisesvn

When I try run project, I saw that error

The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnversion.exe is invalid.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svnversion` is a part of **Command-Line Tools**, installation of which have to be
 enabled and executed in installer of TSVN

Comment: Thank you. I reinstalled that software and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file called svnversion.exe inside TortoiseSVN under bin folder. Please refine the path which you have given like:

`C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnversion.exe` ......   X

---

Try adding it till `bin` directory and check again.